# Contar la cantidad de registros que tiene "1" por cada "Código"

Tags: sql-server

tengo una tabla que tiene una columna de códigos y luego columnas de meses (Ene17,Feb17,Mar17, etc) cada columna de mes contiene 0 y 1; quería saber si se puede hacer un query que me saque las cantidades de código por mes que contengan 1.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT count(codigo) as Enero_16 
FROM [ESTADOS ACUMULADO] 
where [ENE 16]=1 ; allí me cuenta los 1 de Enero
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intentaste algo?

Comment: Podrías dar mas detalles? no entiendo tu pregunta, da mas detalles de tu tabla.

Comment: Pero probaste algo? ademas de mostrar tu tabla?

Comment: eh agregado una imagen a la consulta, e intentato pero lo puedo sacar por un mes, pero para contar los 1 del siguiente mes, mmm no se como seria ya que me hace depender del where que le hice al primer mes.

Comment: SELECT count(codigo) as Enero_16 FROM [ESTADOS ACUMULADO] where [ENE 16]=1 ; alli me cuenta los 1 de Enero

Comment: Lo que buscas es contar la cantidad de registros que tiene "1" por cada "Código" ?

Comment: Asi es Jorge, en Enero pueden haber 100 codigos con 1, en Febrero 150, pueden ser que alguno tuviera 0 o 1 en Enero), es como si lo contara independientemente como hice mi consulta; pero no se si se puede hacer todo junto, gracias por el apoyo

Comment: ok.. agrega eso que intentaste a tu pregunta. y buscamos una solucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alcanza con hacer un sum de cada columna.

Como todos los valores son 1 o 0, te va a mostrar la cuenta de valores que tienen solo 1.

```
SELECT 
    sum([ENE 16]) as Enero_16,
    sum([FEB 16]) as Febrero_16, ...  
FROM [ESTADOS ACUMULADO]
```

Comment: Y cómo saber el total por cada "Código" ? Eso sólo totaliza columnas

Comment: los codigos se repiten?

Comment: Según el OP si.

Comment: yo no lo veo en la pregunta.. fijate el count que hizo. pero si OP lo necesita, modifico la respuesta, alcanza con agregar un group by (codigo)

Comment: exacto, basta con un gruop by, ya que lo pondrás tú, ya no hay necesidad de mi respuesta

Comment: los códigos en este caso son únicos por mes, y pues si no lo vi de esa manera para sacarlo con sum(), gracias por el apoyo, me sirvió de mucho.

Comment: Ah ok, nos entendimos mal entonces.

Comment: @llogo recuerda siempre aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron, y si no sirvieron aclarar porque no sirven, asi le sirve a futuros usuarios.

Comment: a no sabia, gracias por hacerlo presente.

Comment: Entoces por favor @llogo vuelve a leer el [tour] asi sabes como funciona el sitio